# Why I get this exception when i create a dialog?

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to create a dialog in my Libgdx game and I'm getting this Error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:      com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle registered with name: default"
```

this is a part of my json file:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {

default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },

default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some styles defined in your json file, but **you don't have a default style** defined. Also you posted the styles for the ProgressBar, not the Window.

When you define styles you need to always define a style with the name `default`. This style will be chosen in the case you didn't pass a style name parameter while creating your windows.

To fix your json, you could add a style with name `default` or just rename one of your existing ones to `default`. See the [json uiskin example](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json):

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
},
```

For more details check out the [libgdx skins wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin)

Comment: thank you for your answer , but I have already this in my json file: com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
}

Comment: try refreshing the assets folder

Comment: Where does this json file go? What location does it sit at?

Comment: It should usually go into the /assets folder of the android project @HerbMeehan

Comment: Thanks @donfuxx, that's exactly what I did. So lucky guess on my part. It still doesn't work. I'll figure it out eventually. It may even be documented somewhere, but it hasn't jumped out so far. I think the worst part about working with libgdx is that there are almost two major versions. An old version, which is documented all over the place, and a new version, which has different syntax and is not in any tutorial. Basically, I'm doing this the hard way. There's no way I'd get their book, since it is probably outdated.

Comment: I got it, doesn't really matter where it is I guess, just as long as it is there.   Skin uiSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));